# Create a list using dummy variables in R

Tags: arrays, r, list

I have three dummy variables that indicate the source of data

```
                DS1    DS2    DS3
       Pers1     1      0      0
       Pers2     0      1      0
       Pers3     0      1      1
```

And I would like to have

```
                Source
         Pers1   "DS1"
         Pers2   "DS2"
         Pers3   "DS2"|"DS3"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
df = data.frame(DS1 = c(1,0,0), 
                DS2 = c(0,1,1), 
                DS3 = c(0,0,1))
df$source = apply(df == 1, 1, function(x) paste(names(df)[x], collapse = "|"))
> df
  DS1 DS2 DS3  source
1   1   0   0     DS1
2   0   1   0     DS2
3   0   1   1 DS2|DS3
```

Where `apply` loops over the rows of the `df == 1` data.frame and `paste` creates a string.